# How to prepare data for a BULK INSERT command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to dynamically write all fields of a given SQL database table to a file to be later used as the source file for a BULK INSERT command.

I'm using an SqlDataReader to read each field which stores the value as an object.  Depending on the type of the object, I write the value to a file.  This is the code I'm currently using:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

foreach (var fields in rows)
{
    foreach (object val in fields)
    {
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
        {
            if (val is bool)
                writer.Write((bool)val ? 1 : 0);
            else if (val is byte[])
                writer.Write(BitConverter.ToString((byte[])val).Replace("-", ""));
            else if (val is DateTime)
                writer.Write(string.Format("{0} {1}", ((DateTime)val).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ((DateTime)val).ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")));
            else if (val is string)
                writer.Write(((string)val).Replace("\0", string.Empty));
            else
                writer.Write(val);
        }

        // Field terminator
        writer.Write('\0');
    }
}
```

Later, I run the BULK INSERT command as follows:

```
BULK INSERT tableName
FROM 'c:\fileName'
WITH (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\0'
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\0'
   KEEPNULLS
);
```

The issue I have is that I sometimes get an error during the BULK INSERT:  "Unexpected end of file".  It doesn't happen with every row or every table.

I'd like to be able to handle any type of column with any kind of data without errors.

Comment: How on earth could \0 be both a field terminator and a row terminator? How will SQL Server know whether it's reached the end of a field or the end of a row? I suspect you want those to be different, e.g. using a comma for a field terminator and \r\n as a row terminator.

Comment: Since I am reading and writing all columns, MSSQL is smart enough to know that after the nth column the row has ended and the next one begins.  Which is why I don't write the row terminator manually... if I do I get an error saying unexpected null.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a separate issue unrelated with the code above.  The code in my question worked perfectly for over 30GB of data spread across dozens of different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.  It was nothing wrong with my code above.  But I will keep my question here for others to use since I couldn't find an equivalent solution in any of my google searching.

My particular issue was that after writing the files I didn't always close the FileStreams gracefully with a FileStream.Close or Dispose method.  That caused some corruption to the ending bytes of the file where the data had not yet been flushed to disk.

Using the LASTROW parameter in the SQL BULK INSERT command allowed me to successfully import everything in each file up to the row that was corrupt.  And closing my FileStreams properly will ensure this doesn't happen again.